# ignite client node semaphore not reacquiring permit after bouncing

Tags: ignite

I am running Ignite 2.1.0 with 1 server and 1 client node.
My client node acquires the 1 available semaphore permit as follows:

```
IgniteSemaphore semaphore = _ignite.semaphore(name, 1, true, true);
    if(semaphore.tryAcquire()) 
        ...
    }
```

I bounce the client node, confirming that it leaves the topology. On restarting, the tryAcquire() method above returns false. This is not what I was expecting. I expect the client node to reacquire the permit, that was released when the client left the topology. The server node has no code running on it that would attempt to acquire the permit, once it is released

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ignite has a bug. You can watch discussion in this ticket to track plans of fixing it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4173

Note that if a failed node wasn't the last in topology who held an instance of the semaphore, then it will behave as expected.